# SGS3 USB not connecting to PC

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3, running Android 4.1.1.

I am having problems connecting the phone to my PC. I can connect other S3 phones to my PC. So, I presume that it is not the PC (Windows 7) that has problems.

I am using the original Samsung cable. The URT is set to modem and USB is set to PDA.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: phone was charging OK but not recognized as external device.
I found this solution on the Internet and it worked in my case:

1. Power off your phone
2. Power on the phone in **Download mode** (Volume Down + Home + Power)
3. Press Volume Up to continue in Download mode -> you should see an Android bot and some informations about your OS (rooted or standard, ...)
4. Plug your phone into your computer using your USB cable
5. Windows should now discover it and load the driver (from Windows update)
6. Power off your phone
7. Power on the phone (classically this time)

Comment: I followed your steps but nothing happening. Android logo appeared with title downloading but nothing happening. Am I supposed to do any thing else or missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming that you can charge it okay, it is not the cable. Also, other phones get recognized by your computer so it's not that either. However, it's always good to have more than one verification on something. Try plugging your phone into another computer. If that works, you have a problem with your computer. If it doesn't work, the only option left is that it is your phone. I would just back up your data and do a factory reset. If that doesn't fix it, call Samsung.

Comment: Don't rule out the cable that easily: charging uses only 2 of the 4 contacts, data is another one. So also try another cable, just in case -- as you have several devices, you probably also have several cables, so this comes with no extra costs.